# Force input field to return to former correct value on wrong input

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

My app.component.html goes like this:

```html
Type a number below. If it is negative it will be rejected

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="valueId" value="{{ myValue }}" (change)="handleValueChange($event)">
```

and my app.component.test goes like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  myValue: number = 7
  handleValueChange(event: any) {
    const newProposedValue = event.target.value
    if (newProposedValue >= 0) {
      this.myValue = newProposedValue
    }
  }
}
```

If I launch the app, type 5 in the field, hit enter, type
-3 in the field, hit enter, I would like the field's content
to return to 5, the former correct value.

How do I achieve this? I tried adding `else { this.myValue = this.myValue}` after the `if` to simulate a change and force a reloading of the view but that doesn't work.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain his or her reasons ?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter (and they are under no obligation to explain their vote), but [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms) gives you control over when and how data are updated to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to use another state to maintain the previous successful input? Not tailored to Angular, so you'll have to modify it as needed...

```
export class AppComponent {
  myCurrentValue: number = 0;
  myPreviousSuccessValue: number = 1; // or whatever start value you want

  handleValueChange(event: any) {
    this.myCurrentValue = event.target.value;
  }

  handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.myCurrentValue > 0) {
      this.myPreviousSuccessValue = this.myCurrentValue;
    } else {
      this.myCurrentValue = this.myPreviousSuccessValue;
    }
  }

}

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="valueId" value="{{ myCurrentValue }}" (change)="handleValueChange($event)" (submit)="handleOnSubmit($event)">
```

Comment: Worked for me, exactly what I was looking for, thx